# when i post the form : There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddlCarCompany'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model - Class

```
public static  IEnumerable<ClsAdvertismentProperty> GetAdvertismentByDate()
{
    IEnumerable<ClsAdvertismentProperty> AllAdvertisments = from p in db.Advertisment_Tbl
        orderby p.AdvDate descending
        select new ClsAdvertismentProperty
        {
            AdvName = p.AdvName ,
            AdvID =p.AdvID,
            AdvDescripton =p.AdvDescripton,
            CarName =p.CarsSub_Tbl.Cars_Tbl.CarName,
            CarSubName =p.CarsSub_Tbl.CarSubName,
            AdvDate=(DateTime) p.AdvDate
        };
    return AllAdvertisments;
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ClsCarsProperty car = new ClsCarsProperty();
    ViewBag.CarList = new SelectList(ClsBindDropDownLists.GetCars(), "CarID", "CarName");
    return View(ClsAdvertismentOperation.GetAdvertismentByDate());
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCarCompany", ViewBag.CarList as SelectList, "select car", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "styled-select" })
```

Comment: It means that `ViewBag.CarList` is `null` (probably because you submit the form and return the view without re-assigning the `ViewBag.CarList` property

Comment: Thanks problem solved